# How to create git archive of a subfolder and exclude hidden files?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am able to successfully clone a git repository.

Now, I want to `create a zip folder` of the cloned project(which is a subfolder) and want to `exclude` `.git` and .`gitignore` folder/file.

I have so far written below but it is not excluding `.git` and .`gitignore`.

```
git archive -o project.zip HEAD subfoder/*
```

Comment: Why then not simply using `zip` instead of `git archive`?

Comment: When using pathspecs, `git archive` makes an archive containing only the specified paths, so `git archive -o project.zip HEAD -- 'subfolder/*'` should not include `.gitignore` because it is not listed (only `subfolder/*` is listed). Quoting the pathspec is a good idea here so as to protect it from whatever shell you're using, but the details will depend on the shell. Note that when using pathspecs, *negative* pathspecs are also allowed, and if only negative pathspecs are given, Git will archive all else: `git archive HEAD -- ':!.gitignore` will archive everything excluding `.gitignore`.

Comment: In any case, `git archive` *never* puts the `.git` directory into the archive, by definition. So there's something off in your question here.